# UIAlertView show when app loads, open

Tags: iphone, xcode, uialertview

How show a alertview just when the app open, load...

Like everytime that the user open the app, he see the alert ....

Answer (score 1):

write the alert statment in the following appDelegate method,

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
      UIAlertView *alert_View = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your Title" message:@"Your Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"YES",@"NO",nil] autorelease];
    [alert_View show];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Show the alertview in the application delegate class, in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`: and in `applicationWillEnterForeground`:

Answer (score 0):

@Rafeel put this `UIAlertView` in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of your AppDelegate and you will always get the `UIAlertView` when your app launches

```
UIAlertView *confirmAlertView=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Saved" message:@"Want to save!!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel",nil];
    [confirmAlertView show];
    [confirmAlertView release];
```

Hope it Will Help u!